# When should I use WebDev.WebServer.exe?

Tags: iis, iis-express, webdev.webserver, dnu

I have a ASP.NET MVC6 web application developed in VS 2015. I run it on Windows 10. I have client side JavaScript compiled by **Gulp** which is dropped in the **wwwroot** folder which I want to debug as well as debug the WebAPI controllers on the server side. The application will be hosted on Azure after the development is complete.

During the development, should I use (1) WebDev.WebServer.exe (2) IISExpress.exe (3) IIS10 or (4) DNU to host the ASP.NET website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express (2) is good enough for about 95% of things you need to do during development, it's as good an implementation of "proper" IIS7+ as you'll likely need.

That said, for things you can't properly emulate on your workstation, such as Azure, periodic deployment to your Azure environment is always a good idea, just to be sure you don't fall into the trap of *"Well it worked on my machine"*.

Never use the built-in webserver.exe, it's a toy and is severely limited in functionality.